# How to fix ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [ktsircinfo_num1], [5], [104], [2789130], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Tags: oracle

I change the table from non-partitioned to partitioned using

```
ALTER table schema.table_name MODIFY partition by list(column_name)
automatic (partition p_null values(null))
```

but its corrupt and throws

> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [ktsircinfo_num1], [5], [104], [2789130], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

I check index on `column_name` have been partitioned but table has not and table has no segments in dba_segments.

Now, I can't do anything with this table. I try dbms_repair, drop index, drop table, truncate, delete, select but all of them throw

> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [ktsircinfo_num1], [5], [104], [2789130], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Can anyone help me!!!

Comment: ORa-600 is an internal Oracle error and usually let's to a incident at Oracle support.

Comment: Have a look at [Primary Note for Diagnosing ORA-600 Doc ID 1092832.1](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1092832_1.html), which mentions [ORA-00600 Lookup tool (Note 153788.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=10075609483493&id=153788.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=pxdpl3rpu_80) (requires My Oracle Support account and database version).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error can not fix simply without Oracle expert. But if your data is not important, you can use following simple trick (you need sysdba permission to do this)

1. Rename old table in sys.obj$

```
update sys.obj$ set name = 'new_name' where name = 'old_name' and owner# = <owner_id in sys.user$>;
```

2. Flush shared pool to apply new name

```
alter system flush shared_pool;
```

You may also have to rename related objects like index, trigger, constraint, ... Looking for object id in sys.ind$, sys.trigger$, ... and rename its in sys.obj$

Now you can recreate table and using it again

Comment: This is potentially a dangerous suggestion ... it is NOT recommended to run any inserts/updates against  internal oracle tables without first consulting with Oracle support.  I wouldn't recommend this without Oracle support (and even then, would question them GREATLY on this).   
That said . prior to anything like this .. of course .. get a backup prior to doing it .. "just in case" ;)